# Is there something that convert the stuff  read from input port to some specific type in Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket

Is there can convert the stuff read from input port to some specific type in Racket? like turning the stuff read from piped port into a defined struct? if not, then how can process communication resume those data types passed back and forth?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read about the [`racket/serialize`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/serialization.html) library in [the guide](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/serialization.html) and also see the `#:prefab` option for [`struct`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/define-struct.html) that can create struct types that can always be read with `read` -- it's also described in [the chapter on structs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/define-struct.html#%28part._prefab-struct%29) in the guide.